# Why isn't my mapview using the constraints to be full screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

[image]

This is currently what I'm working with. I have repeatedly set the constraints to 0, 0, 0, 0 and with constrain to margins unchecked. However, ever time I run the simulator it's not filling the screen but remaining at 600x600. I have height and width unchecked so the only constraints I have added are -20 -> 0 and 20 -> 0.

And are size classes just for tablet & iPhone functionality, or can I unselect and have the app geared towards iPhone but still manage changes in sizes from iPhone to iPhone?

EDIT: Unchecked size classes and have iPhone selected, but am still getting the issue of a square mapview.

EDIT2: Added the image of the constraints here, for some reason it's either not saving or using the constraints loaded. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjTPf.jpg

SOLVED: For whatever reason, xcode wasn't adding the top and bottom constraints to 0. "Adding missing constraints" fixed the problem.

Comment: Add an image of your constraints

Comment: As well as more constraint information, do you have any `UIView`s that may be covering up the map?

Comment: Added the pictures of the constraints, no other UIViews covering it up, because if I tick the height constraint and make it 100 more than it currently it, it registers that. I'm not sure if the constraints aren't applying. I'm new to XCode so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't seem as if the constraint are going underneath the mapview, but instead are on the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you answered your own question, but I'm just going to put an answer here for anyone later having this problem.

If you see a red outline, or red constraints in interface builder, that indicates that you have an error (due to something like a missing or conflicting constraint). If you're getting a red outline/constraint you won't get what you're looking for when you run the app.
You should try and fix this problem to get the desired outcome.

In your case You have a leading and trailing constraint, however this is not sufficient, and you must add a top and bottom margin.

When your outline is orange/yellow, this means that you have a warning, it's not going to break, but something is out of place. This usually fixes itself if you click `update frames` under `resolve auto layout issues` at the bottom right of the screen.

[image]

Also if you want to have a full screen map on all devices consider adding your constraints in the `any - any` class.

Comment: So I would like a full screen map on all iPhones, but I'm exactly concerned with a tablet at this point, based on the nature of the app. Should I still be dealing with size classes if it's strictly iPhone?

Comment: Yes, because size classes aren't just for different devices, it's also different orientations. Unless your app is strictly iPhone portrait, then you can stick to all iPhones in portrait size class.

Comment: So I've gotten it to work, but I've now added a seach bar at the top. My constraints are similar to the toolbar but with the bottom of the search bar object being where the map view object starts. Even after updating frames and adding missing constraints, the map view is, I imagine, covering up the search bar. Screenshot http://imgur.com/bdOiaGx

Comment: I can't see anything wrong without asking more questions about it, but this is probably better asked as a seperate question. Once you've asked it you can link that question here if you'd like.

Comment: yeah I just did that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563012/my-navigation-bar-is-showing-up-in-storyboard-but-not-in-the-simulator