# My navigation bar is showing up in storyboard but not in the simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

When trying to add a navigation bar for searching on the left button and eventually a setting button on the right bar button, the bar isn't showing up in the simulator. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIK1V.jpg)

Should I be using a regular toolbar like the temporary one I have on the bottom? I'd prefer the search button for loading new addresses, and settings for the obvious, but then I want buttons that serve as navigations for moving from tab to tab. Should I simply implement a search bar above the map view and a settings button on the right? I'm new to xcode and it's kicking my ass.

EDIT: After changing the hidden to "self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)" the toolbar appeared but at the bottom below the current toolbar with zoom and type buttons. So it looks as if it thinks it's a toolbar and only wants to put it at the bottom?

Comment: Click the debug view hierarchy button on top of the console while the app is running, and post a picture of what you see.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure to what you're referring.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: You're not meant to setToolbarHidden, because it's already there, you want setNavigationBarHidden

Comment: Yes, but even when I set it's hidden attribute to false, it's not showing up. All the guides I have seen online simply do -> view -> embed in navigation. All I've done after that is move the upper boundary of the map view down to accommodate for the bar. Then I just added a left bar button and changed the icon to search.

Comment: So how do I unembed it, I tried simply deleting the scene but that deletes the navigation bar completely. And deleting the scene makes the entire simulation black.

Comment: If you use git you can rebase - given that you committed. Or you can undo till you get there.

Comment: So I've backed up all the way, and instead of embedding I simply added a navigation bar to the view. But it's still not showing up with everything I've been told to do.

Comment: Ok, go back to just before you add it. Click on your navigation controller, and tick `show navigation bar` in the attributes inspector

Comment: Well I don't think it's already embedded in a navigation controller. The storyboard entry point is just before the view controller in the story board. All I want to do is add UI, I'm not even working on methods and it's already a terrible experience.

Comment: So now you want to embed it, just make sure that it's not embedded in 2 navigation controllers

Comment: It was never embedded in more than one, so I'm not sure what I've done now.

Comment: Can you share a picture please?

Comment: This is all you need to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9239246/2803660

Comment: This is what I'm working with. http://imgur.com/a/e6lW2 I only have one view controller, I'm not trying to hide in one and show in another. That intuitively makes sense, but I have no idea why it's not working. I wish I had the option to hardcode these things like in JAVA.

Comment: Try moving the `setNavigationBarHidden` to `viewWillAppear` but that won't solve the issue. You did something incorrect in the storyboard. Having a navigation controller shouldn't give you such a hard time.

Comment: You don't currently have much, I would honestly start with a new view controller, and test it every step.

Comment: I'm back to square one with things still not working. It's probably a great IDE but it involves 0 actual coding for the design and I have no experience with any of it.

Comment: That's why you need to read up, follow tutorials.
Start from the beginning, try to create the navigation bar first, get that working, then add the map view.

Comment: Follow this for example: http://sweettutos.com/2015/04/24/swift-mapkit-tutorial-series-how-to-search-a-place-address-or-poi-in-the-map/

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = false;
```

Use above code to show navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you might be aligning the top of the Map View to the top of the top layout guide, if this is the case your toobar might be hidden behind the map view. I would change that constraint that constraint in the map view and use "vertical spacing" to the tool bar in the top and give it a value of 0.

Comment: It's currently set to the bottom of top layout guide, but in the storyboard it only shows the constraints going up to right below the navigation bar. So I figured the bottom of top layout guide is the bottom of the navigation, at least that's what it's visually implying.

Comment: I don't think that would be the case, if your constraint to the bottom of the top layout guide has a value of 0, then the map view will be bound to the top view. add constraints to your navigation bar and have the map view have of vertical spacing = 0 to your nav bar. 

You can debug this with the view hierarchy [like so](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html), or use the preview mode to see how it will look without the simulator, http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-preview-storyboards-in-interface-builder/

Answer (score 0):

Don't add navigation bar manually If you are adding. You will get Your navigation bar with your navigation controller. In your `viewWillAppear()`
put the line of code `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 solution**

Add this code to your ViewController:

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    }
```